# Jquery Autocomplete source called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function that attaches an autocomplete to textbox. Problem is that it calls twice. I have created drop down list to select type, when I select type and write any text in text box the autocomplete calls only once and after that I have changed the type and this time it calls previous autocomplete source method and then calls the new one source method.(for e.g. if I select type `case` for 1st time and `contact` for 2nd time then it call `case` source method 1st and then calls `else(Contact)` source method ) Select type values (`Case`, `Contact`). Sample data return from ajax (`Soft Client testing@@2328||Test@@2258||TEst Entity@@2384||Test company@@2382`)

```
function LoadData() {
    var Type = $('#slctType').val();
    var Text = $('#tags').val();
    if (Type == "Case") {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                alert("Case");
                $.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": Type, "Text": Text }, function (data) {
                    try {
                        if (data != null) {
                            if (data.indexOf('error') == 0) {
                                display(data, "Error");
                            }
                            else {
                                var arrData = data.split("@@");
                                var sourceData = [];

                                for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                                    var arrValue = arrData[i].split("||");
                                    sourceData.push({ "value": arrValue[0], "label": arrValue[1] });
                                }
                                if (sourceData.length != 0) {
                                    response($.map(sourceData, function (item) {
                                        return item;
                                    }));
                                }
                                else {
                                    response([]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Error) {
                        display("On text change : " + Error, "Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                ID = ui.item.value;

            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            var arrV = item.value.split("-");
            var listItem = $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a class = '" + arrV[1] + "Color'>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            return listItem;
        };
    }
    else {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                alert("Non Case");
                $.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": Type, "Text": Text }, function (data) {
                    try {
                        if (data != null) {
                            if (data.indexOf('error') == 0) {
                                display(data, "Error");
                            }
                            else {
                                var arrData = data.split("@@");
                                var sourceData = [];

                                for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                                    var arrValue = arrData[i].split("||");
                                    sourceData.push({ "value": arrValue[0], "label": arrValue[1] });
                                }
                                if (sourceData.length != 0) {
                                    response($.map(sourceData, function (item) {
                                        return item;
                                    }));
                                }
                                else {
                                    response([]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Error) {
                        display("On text change : " + Error, "Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                ID = ui.item.value;

            }
        });
    }
}

function ChangeType() {
    $('#tags').val('');
    ID = 0;
    $("#tags").removeData('autocomplete');
    $('#tags').autocomplete("destroy");
}

function OnTextChange(event) {
    LoadData();
}

<select id="slctType" onchange="ChangeType();">
    <option value="Case">Case</option>
    <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
    <option value="BOL">BOL</option>
    <option value="Security">Security</option>
    <option value="CompanyName">Entity Name</option>
</select>

<input id="tags" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:OnTextChange(event);" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

Comment: I would guess it's because you assign an autocomplete handler to the element, then when the LoadData function runs again, you assign another one, without removing the previous one.

Comment: How to remove previous data?

Comment: Did you spend any time with the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-destroy . Run that before you create each new autocomplete.

Comment: Yes i have already used this in ChangeType() function.

Comment: It would make more sense to put it at the start of the LoadData function really. I can't even see, from your code, when this ChangeType() function actually runs.

Comment: if you have extra code please add it to the question itself. Code inside comments is hard to read, as you can see.

Comment: I have used drop down option for that, when drop down type is changed ChangeType() function is called.

Comment: I have added html code in question

Comment: so wait a minute...LoadData() runs every single time the user types???? That's crazy and makes no sense. It's trying to re-create the autocomplete at the same time that the autocomplete is trying to do its work - the autocomplete waits for a keyup event on the same element!! You only need to run the LoadData() when the user changes the selection - it's just there to _initialise_ the autocomplete. Get rid of your onkeyup and put a call to LoadData() at the end of the ChangeType() function. You might also need to run it once when the page loads as well, to initialise it with the default option

Comment: i agree with your suggestion but my question is to why it show previous Type and also new Type entries at once? For e.g. if i set Type "Case" and search some text. And next time changed the type to "Contact", that time it 1st runs and shows "Case" type entries and then "Contact" Type entries

Comment: Also i have tried your suggestion but not worked

Comment: Well you certainly need to do my suggestion for a start because what you have got now makes no sense. It may not be fully the solution but it's certainly a necessary step in the right direction.

Comment: Another problem could be `$.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": Type, "Text": Text }, function (data) {
` - you're supposed to use `request.term` to get what the user is currently typing. Instead you're sending what was in the textbox the last time LoadData ran, which may not be the same. Same for the "Type". Try `$.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": $('#slctType').val(), "Text": request.term }, function (data) {` to send up-to-date info to the server

Comment: It seems to be running correctly. Thank you for the clarification. Please post your answer separately, so i can mark it as answer.

Comment: That's great. I've written up my two main suggestions into an answer. thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `LoadData()` runs every single time the user types. That makes no sense. It's trying to re-create the autocomplete at the same time that the autocomplete is trying to do its work - the autocomplete waits for a keyup event on the same element! You only need to run the LoadData() when the user changes the selection - it's just there to initialise the autocomplete. Get rid of your `onkeyup` on the "tags" element and put a call to `LoadData()` at the end of the `ChangeType()` function instead. You might also need to run it once when the page loads as well, to initialise it with the default option

Also

```
$.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": Type, "Text": Text }, function (data) {
```

is a problem - you're supposed to use `request.term` to get what the user is currently typing - see http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source in the "function" section of the entry. Instead right now you're sending what was in the textbox the last time LoadData ran, which may not be the same. Same for the "Type".

Use

```
$.post('../MasterPages/Ajax/ajaxSearch.ashx', { "Type": $('#slctType').val(), "Text": request.term }, function (data) {
```

to send up-to-date info to the server.